# Extract the different css transformations from a transform string?

Tags: javascript, css, regex, css-transforms

Here is an example CSS transform string:

```
rotate(-10 50 100)
translate(-36 45.5)
skewX(40)
scale(1 0.5)
```

From this string I want to either

- get one string for each transformation
- get an object with properties I can access

How can I do this?

My best idea is to use RegEx, but I haven't figured out a working RegEx solution:

```
[a-z]+?\([\-a-z0-9\s]*?\)
```

https://regex101.com/r/Ycjuxz/1

You are also welcome to have a different idea for a solution that does not use RegEx.

Comment: Split by `\n`, and then use RegExp to get the function names and the values for the arguments.

Comment: @Teemu: not enough. It is only the example string that uses line breaks. I think the spec for css transformations allows different whitespaces as well. Also your solution would break between each argument as well.

Comment: @user1283776 How are you getting the CSS transform string (in your example)? Could you show an example snippet?

Comment: @Richard: The top example on this page is an example of a CSS transform string: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform. I just get the transform strings as string using querySelector(element).getAttribute("transform"). I don't know of anything more clever I could use.

Comment: For a RegExp, we'd need complete examples of the source string, "just an example" is not enough. It's not hard to split by any white-space, though.

Comment: Off the top of my head I went with `\w+\(.*\)` which seemed to work fine given your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick example of how you might do this using a regular expression and reducing the results down to an object:

```
function parseTransform(transform) {
    return Array.from(transform.matchAll(/(\w+)\((.+?)\)/gm))
        .reduce((agg, [, fn, val]) => ({
            ...agg,
            [fn]: val
        })
        , {});
}

const res = parseTransform(`rotate(-10 50 100)
translate(-36 45.5)
skewX(40)
scale(1 0.5)`);
```

The output of this is

```
{rotate: "-10 50 100", translate: "-36 45.5", skewX: "40", scale: "1 0.5"}
```

In this version we overwrite the value of a function if it appears twice. You could merge them together if some properties can appear more than once.

Comment: Thanks! But it doesn't give the correct answer for this reasonable string: "translate(200 200) skewX(40)". Maybe if you modify it slightly to this? "(\w+)\((.+?)\)"

Comment: @user1283776 Yes good point! Thanks. I've updated my answer to reflect this change.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Teemu's comment:

```js
const text=`rotate(-10 50 100)
translate(-36 45.5)
skewX(40)
scale(1 0.5)`;
const rows = text.split('\n');
const transformations = rows.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  const key = cur.substring(0, cur.indexOf('('));
  const value = cur.replace(key, '').replace('(', '').replace(')', '');
  acc[key] = value;
  return acc
}, {});

console.log(transformations);
```